# Firebird 3.0.7 Install incomplete, please read the Compatibility chapter in the release notes for this version

Tags: sql, linux, база-данных, windows

Поставил файрбёрд 64-битной версии, IBExpert работает нормально, а вот, например, встроенная утилита Firebird ISQL Tool при написании команды `CONNECT localhost:employee user SYSDBA password masterkey;`

Выдаёт

```
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 28000
Install incomplete, please read the Compatibility chapter in the release notes for this version
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, кто сталкивался...3 сутки уже сижу не понимаю, в чём проблема...

Comment: please read the Compatibility chapter in the release notes for this version - это сделано?

Comment: @gbg, интересно, что чекать) Впрочем, я проблему решил, ща ответ напишу

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение проблемы: в файле firebird.conf заменить

```
AuthServer = Legacy_Auth
AuthClient = Legacy_Auth
WireCrypt = Disabled
```

Таким образом